# How to filter the data in json column in a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a table `candidate`:

```
id | name | info

|---|------|--------------------------------------------------------------

 1  | apps | \[{"exp": "1","skill": "python"},{"exp": "2","skill": "c" }\]

 2  | Ravi | \[{"exp": "1","skill": "python"},{"exp": "1","skill": "java" }\]
```

I need to query and filter to the candidates with skill = "python" and exp = "1" using an index.

I am trying to add a column and add an index on the table in MySql 8.0.32:

```
ALTER TABLE candidate

ADD exp_skills_json JSON GENERATED ALWAYS AS (JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('skill', info-\>\>'$.skill', 'exp', info-\>\>'$.exp'))) VIRTUAL,ADD INDEX idx_exp_skills_json ((exp_skills_json));
```

However, I got an error code 1111.

How can I add the index so that my query can execute effectively?

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can't make an index on a JSON array of objects.

The closest thing is in MySQL 8.0, to make a [multi-valued index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) on a JSON array of same-typed scalars. But that doesn't work for the example you show, which is an array of objects.

In the example you show, the JSON objects all have the same fields, `exp` and `skill`. You should create a second table with columns `exp` and `skill`, and store one pair per row.

```
CREATE TABLE candidate_skills (
  candidate_id INT NOT NULL,
  skill VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  exp INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (candidate_id, skill),
  KEY (exp, skill),
  FOREIGN KEY (candidate_id) REFERENCES candidate(id)
);
```

There is no reason to use JSON in the example you show, and it's not possible to optimize it with an index.

Comment: Thank you bill karwin.
But I try avoid joins in above example .

Comment: Well that's the only way you can optimize with an index, and that's what you asked in your question.